# Enabling site-wide RSS in Plone

Tags: rss, plone

I am a plone newbie and I'm trying to set up a site-wide RSS feed of all my site's content in Plone 4.0.7

I have followed the instructions here:
http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-community-developer-documentation/functionality/rss
I've partially succeeded - I created the content collection, and the RSS feed is working:
http://nitric.co.za/site-feed/RSS

The problem is <link type="alternate"... /> is not appearing on every page of the site.

The instructions suggest that in ZMI -> portal_actions -> site_actions there should be a record for RSS. There was no such record in my installation. However under portal_actions -> document_actions there was so I cut and paste it into site_actions however this had no effect.

What is the best way to get the RSS link tag to appear in the html header of every page on my site?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, site_actions are not document_actions and neither have ever appeared in the <head> element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

site_actions are the links at the bottom of your page (eg Site Map, Accessibility, Contact)
those won't help you in getting  elements to your header.

to have all your feeds available on all pages throughout your portal you need to create a custom theme package and either

- register a custom viewlet or
- customize the main_template

i quickly checked the collective repository (http://dev.plone.org/collective/browser) for packages named *rss* and found http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.siterss which pretty much sounds like it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you - collective.siterss does exactly what I wanted without having to customize templates or register custom viewlets.